# Storing blog entries on one blog site and referencing it from other sites in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We are using SharePoint 2010 Enterprise and have around 5 publishing sites on it for different business units. All of these publishing sites have a blog. The management wants to have a single blog site where entries can be made and then every one of those sites could pull data from this central blog site using something like taxonomy.

I have been searching for a way to see if this is even possible using the built-in webparts. The only thing I have found out is to create custom webparts (to display list of blogs, a single blog and a webpart to display 5 recent posts). We could program this Webpart to pull data from this central blog site.

Is this a good way of going forward or do you think there is a better way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a content query web part to retrieve the particular blog entires you want.  I have done that to display the latest news items on the my SharePoint site's home page.

Another way to do this is to SharePoint's web services and use the client side object model with JavaScript or jQuery to retrieve and display your blog entries.